# Is it ok if i accidentally masturbated? (i’m a girl)

Tags: masturbation

I have an infection, down there which causes a lot of irritation like a lot a lot! all over my pubic area, my inner thighs and my vagina too and as i was itching and itching even around my clitoris i started trembling and i think i reached orgasm but there was no fluid released whatsoever. So i wanted to ask is it still haram as i didn’t do it on purpose. My infection is undiagnosed rn so ill get it checked soon

Comment: there is difference of opinion among scholars whether masturbation is haraam or not.